# How to destroy cookies on page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh

Hello I need to destroy javascript cookies on a page refresh. I need to set a new bunch of cookies on every page load which help me render the web page based on user options. Is there a method to destroy cookies on a page refresh??

Comment: If you rewrite the cookies the old values disappear.

Comment: well what would the event be, when I rewrite my cookies??

Comment: if your page loads after onunload then you are refreshing so you could test the age of a cookie you set in onunload and onload see if it is less than a minute old, you refreshed

Answer (score 3):

May be you could remove cookies on page unload.

For example, with jQuery:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  //Destroy cookies here
});
```

Comment: do we have unload in javascript??

Comment: of course! :) http://api.jquery.com/unload/   http://www.codetoad.com/javascript/miscellaneous/onunload_event.asp

Comment: hey but is this a page refresh?? this is when you navigate away from the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the page refresh, have a look at:

[Detecting Page Refreshes :: Using JavaScript on Client-Side](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php)

Once you know that, you should be able to delete the cookies.