# Delete cookies on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, page-refresh

How do I delete cookies via JavaScript when you refresh a page ? I wanted to do this using the event `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you want to remove a cookie before it has a chance to be sent back to the server is beyond me, but here you go:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    document.cookie = 'cookiename=; expires=' + d.toGMTString() + ';';
};
```

Comment: I wanted to do this using the event onbeforeunload.

Comment: Then the path and domain cookie metadata might need to be set as well.  *Everything* except the expires value and the cookie value itself must be identical to the original cookie.  Additionally, have you tested with a debugger to see if the function is even being executed?

Comment: Thanks, I found your question. It turns out it is already set. Here it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365178/how-to-destroy-cookies-on-page-refresh